# R - Tally for multiple factors in a column

Tags: r, function, lapply, tapply, tally

I have a sample data.frame, "events" which has multiple prey captures occurring on a single dive. Based on the Capture column, I have used the word "handling" to tally up the number of captures per dive.

However, in some instances I have multiple prey types in a single dive. How can I work out the number of prey captures based on species (i.e. how many fish.a and how many fish.b caught in a single dive)?

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
events <- data.frame(Prey_present =c("fish.a", "fish.a","", "fish.b", 
"fish.b","fish.b"),
Capture = c("","","handling", "", "", "handling") ,
Dive_id =c("dive.1", "dive.1","dive.1", "dive.1","dive.1", "dive.1"))

temp<- tapply(events$Capture, events$Dive_id, function(x) rle(x == 
"handling"))
ncaptures<- data.frame(id = names(temp), 
tally = unlist(lapply(temp, function(x) sum(x$values))))
final<-ncaptures[order(ncaptures$id),]
```

My final output (which I will bind to my bigger data.frame) should be something like:

```
final <- data.frame(fish.a =c(1),
fish.b = c(1),
Dive_id =c("dive.1"))
```

Comment: you can use aggregate function to find out the total number of preys captured in a single dive

Comment: @Hunaidkhan yes I've tried to aggregate by dive but it is not reliable as the numbers I would get from the Prey_present column would not reflect the actual number of things being caught.

Comment: Can you do one thing just provide screenshot or dput() of the expected output, i will help you out with the code.

Comment: table(events1$Dive_id,events1$Prey_present) this will work

Comment: @Hunaidkhan your suggestion gives a count of the column "Prey_present". What I'm trying to work out is a count of handling for each factor in Prey_present in a single id/dive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the Capture column and use the `dplyr` library to aggregate

```
library(dplyr)

capture_tally <- events %>% group_by(Dive_id, Prey_present) %>% 
    summarise(Count_of_Captures = n())
```

It will group by Dive_id and Prey_Present. then use the `summarise` function to perform the counts for each particular dive and prey type captured.

You can name the `Count_of_Captures` column whatever you want.

EDIT: Here's the output of the above code.

```
 Dive_id        Prey_present         Count_of_Captures
  <fctr>       <fctr>               <int>
1  dive.1                              1
2  dive.1       fish.a                 2
3  dive.1       fish.b                 3
```

EDIT: ok, try this.

```
library(tidyr); 

events %>% group_by(Dive_id, Prey_present) %>% 
   filter(Capture != "") %>%  # filter out captured ones (handling)
   summarise(Count = n()) %>%  #get the count for each fish type (long format)
   spread(Prey_present, Count) # Use the spread() function from tidyr package to convert the data from long to wide format
```

I'm guessing you're anytime the Capture Column is blank, no fish has been captured. and that you're counting only the instances it says `handling`. I might have misunderstood you again, so I apologize.

Comment: Can you include your output as a dput? When I run your suggested code, I still get the same result (i.e. the sum of the prey present column)

Comment: This still does not answer my question. The preycapture column indicates something is captured, not the prey present column. So 2 things are captured. Fisha once and Fishb once. See output that I am looking for in my question. Thanks for giving it a go!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)               
new1<- events %>% group_by(Dive_id,Prey_present) %>% summarise(Capture = NROW(Capture))
```

this will give you required output

Comment: Still not giving the right thing. The code still produces a count of prey_present column. The output of dput(new1): 
structure(list(Dive_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "dive.1", 
    class = "factor"), 
               Prey_present = structure(1:3, .Label = c("", "fish.a", "fish.b"
               ), class = "factor"), Capture = 1:3), row.names = c(NA, -3L
               ), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = list(
                 Dive_id), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("Dive_id", "Prey_present", 
                                                   "Capture"))